# Select Rootnode from a WPF-TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, treeview

How to programmatically select the rootnode from a wpf treeview in c# that is databindet with a xmlDataProvider?

In my case the Rootnode is from DataType="cards":

```
<cards>
    <category />
    <card />
    <card />
    <card />
</cards>
```

I tried this:

```
//AddNode
xmlDataProvider.Document.DocumentElement["cards"].AppendChild(newNode);

//Select rootnode
treeView.SelectedValuePath = "cards";
//the hard way:
//treeView.SelectedValuePath = ((XmlNode)treeView.Items.GetItemAt(0)).Name.LocalName";

treeView.Focus();
```

but the Rootnode isn´t selected :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made it :-)

```
var treeViewItem = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as TreeViewItem;

treeViewItem.Focus();
```

Comment: @cd491415 if it doesn't work, it could be because the treeview items have not yet been generated from the source data.

Answer (score 0):

(treeView.Items[0] as TreeViewItem).Focus(); should work, i think.

Comment: Ok, i see now that not **so** easy when you use xmldataprovider... :(

Comment: your code creates a NullReferenceException, i have tested this way my self before i created this question ;-)

Comment: Yeah, after i wrote it i wrote a test, but it failed. I never worked with binding xmls, so sorry for the fals alarm.